# Data inconsistency in multithread program

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, apache-storm

I have a problem in data consistency using multithreaded programming.

Use case: I will get messages(Person information) in a queue. I have a multithread code which takes data from queue and put it to another database. Here I need to compare person information and, if there is any duplicate, I need to merge/update and insert it to another database.

**Problem**: If two similar person objects are in two different thread at the same time, both treats this person as it is not there in the second database and both tries to insert it - so here we will have duplicate records.

How can I solve the above problem?

> Conceptually if I get to know how to do, I can code for this in Java or am using Apache storm and run parallel process.

Comment: You will need to shyncronize the threads.

Comment: Will `messages` queue ever have duplicates?

Comment: i had similar problem. so I used a Distrobuter. it basically grabs a task if no similar task is processing atm, then it creates a new thread and give it the task.. however in my case Distrobuter can create up to 400 threads

Comment: @Dagriel I should process a large set of data, so if i synchronize its something like single thread then my performance goes down.

Comment: @JAtkin yes messages in queue will have duplicates

Comment: Do you have a single database update method that's not present in each thread? If so, you could synchronize that method, which could do your check for duplicates.

Comment: @nafas what is Distrobuter? can you send me any link so that i can understand.

Comment: mate, this is just a name I came up my self. its just a Thread and constantly run and "Distrobute" the tasks. it can be useful if Thread processing is much slower than retrieving tasks. if its not ur case then no point of having it

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @medvedev1088 Titan, mongodb

Comment: @Shri Titan supports transactions and ACID but serializable isolation is only available for BerkleyDB storage http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/tx.html. Check out my answer for more details. Also in the link they talk about multi-threaded transactions which may be useful for your case.

Comment: When inserting the Person do you need to insert in a single database or multiple database e.g. both in Mongo and Titan? If you need to keep consistency across multiple databases then you can look at distributed transactions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction. But I guess a simpler approach is to do synchronization yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Check duplicate when u insert to the queue. Maintain a hashtable besides the queue. Every time u insert to the queue, check whether the data is already in the hashtable. if so, discard the insert. The complexity of insertion will still be O(1), but memory cost added.
2. Instead of inserting to a single queue, insert to multiple queues according to the hash value. One consumer thread process one queue. This is also a common way to maintain time series data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple locking mechanism a long time ago that locks on the value of an object rather than the instance.  It's a little slow, but if you have some key that is equal on both threads it might work.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Isaiah van der Elst (isaiah.v@comcast.net)
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
 *   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   
 * - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *   
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

package org.gearman.impl.util;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * A simple lock based on the value of an object instead of the object's instance.
 * 
 * The synchronizing problem in the server is that sometimes it's required to
 * synchronize on a key value for a hash table. However, the key being used will
 * never be the same instance from one thread to another, and synchronizing on the
 * hash table itself will be too slow.  Currently synchronization is done by this
 * lock which locks based on Object value, not the Object's instance.
 * 
 * Synchronization could have been done using primitive Objects, like Integers,
 * but I decided not to because this program is designed to be embedded. That
 * kind of synchronization may interfere with the wrapping program, possibly
 * causing a deadlock that is impossible to find. 
 * 
 * @author isaiah.v
 */
public class EqualsLock {

        /** The set of all keys and lock owners */
        private final Map<Object, Thread> keys = new HashMap<Object, Thread>();

        /**
         * Accrues a lock for the given key. If this thread acquires a lock with
         * key1, any subsequent threads trying to acquire the lock with key2 will
         * block if key1.equals(key2).  If key1.equals(key2) is not true, the
         * subsequent thread will acquire the lock for key2 and continue execution.
         * 
         * @param key
         *              The key 
         */
        public final void lock(final Object key) {
                boolean isInterrupted = false;

                try {
                        synchronized(keys){

                                while(!acquireLock(key, Thread.currentThread())) {
                                        keys.wait();
                                }
                        }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // Ignore the interruption until we've finished
                        isInterrupted = Thread.interrupted();
                }

                if(isInterrupted) {
                        // re-interrupt thread if an interruption occured
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
        }

        /**
         * Acquires the lock only if it is free at the time of invocation.
         * 
         * Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately with the
         * value true. If the lock is not available then this method will return
         * immediately with the value false.
         * 
         * @param key
         *              The key to acquire the lock
         * @return      
         *              true if the lock was acquired, false if the lock was not acquired 
         */
        public final boolean tryLock(final Object key) {
                synchronized(keys) {
                        return acquireLock(key, Thread.currentThread());
                }
        }

        /**
         * Releases the lock of the given key.  The lock is only released if the
         * calling thread owns the lock for the given key
         * 
         * @param key The key
         */
        public final void unlock(final Object key) {
                synchronized(keys){
                        if(keys.get(key)==Thread.currentThread()) {
                                keys.remove(key);
                                keys.notifyAll();
                        }
                }
        }

        /**
         * Adds the (Object,Thread) pair if the key is not already in the key set.
         * 
         * @param key   The key to add
         * @param t             The Thread to be associated with the key
         * @return
         *              true if the Thread t and the Object key is successfully added, or
         *              Thread t is already associated with Object key. false if the Object
         *              key has already been added but Thread t is not associated with it.
         */
        private final boolean acquireLock (final Object key, final Thread t) {
                final Thread value = keys.get(key);

                if(value == t)
                        return true;
                if(value != null)
                        return false;

                keys.put(key, t);
                return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Note: I think I see a bug if the thread is interrupted on lock.

Answer (score 0):

If the database that you use supports transactions and transaction isolation you can rely on that. You will probably need to use [Serializable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Serializable) isolation level to avoid [Phantom Reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Phantom_reads). Each validate + update/insert operation should be performed in a single transaction.

**Explanation:**
The problem that you described is a kind of concurrency effect. It is called Phantom Reads. Imagine that first you check if the database table already contains a person with firstname "test" by using a select query. The query returns an empty result set. So you decide to insert this person to the database. In the meantime just after you issued the select query but before you issued the insert query another thread is trying to do the same thing i.e. check if the database contains the person with name "test". The second thread inserts the person to the database. If the first thread issues the same select query after it perform the insert and observes that there are 2 rows instead of expected 1 (that it just inserted) that's the phantom read. You can read more about isolation and concurrency effects in this Wikipedia article [Isolation (database systems)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems))

If your database doesn't support transactions or Serializable isolation level you will need to synchronise yourself. If all the threads are in a single JVM you can use synchronized keyword or ReentrantReadWriteLock. If the threads are in different JVM's you can use distributed lock service (Terracotta or Hazelcast).